# Упрощение содержимого string

Tags: c++, строки

Допустим, есть у нас:

```
string a = <p style="text-align:center;"><strong>Primary Link: <a href="http://www.mediafire.com/download/90wqj6d0n86h7z1/YandereSimMay7th.rar">http://www.mediafire.com/download/90wqj6d0n86h7z1/YandereSimMay7th.rar</a></strong></p>
```

и нужно его обрезать слева и справа, чтоб вышло:

```
string a = http://www.mediafire.com/download/90wqj6d0n86h7z1/YandereSimMay7th.rar
```

Необходимо удалить символы до "http" и после "rar", при этом удалив так же "дубликат". Вопрос в том, ***как это сделать?***
Попрошу с примером, так как я новичок в С++.

Comment: Если вы новичок в C++, воспользуйтесь тем языком, в котором вы не новичок. И да, для разбора HTML обычно пользуются готовым парсером, а не изобретают велосипед.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотря что *именно* вам нужно.
Если именно первый URL - подход один, если первый URL в тэге `<a>` - немного другой и т.д. Можно, например, использовать регулярные выражения.

Так как вы новичок, давайте и задачу упростим - найти `href="URL"`, и выбрать из него URL.

Находим положение `href="` в строке

```
size_t pos = a.find("href=\"");
```

и, если найдено, обрезаем строку слева, пропуская 6 символов `href="`

```
if (pos != string::npos) a = a.substr(pos + 6);
```

Затем ищем кавычки и обрезаем справа

```
pos = a.find('"');
if (pos != string::npos) a = a.substr(0,pos);
```

Все.

Для данного конкретного случая :) Сами понимаете, что из `<img>` искать надо чуть иначе, ну, совет посмотреть парсер вам уже дали. И еще - из опыта - HTML не XML, он даже по стандарту допускает вольности, ну, а если даже XML встречается кривой, то что уж говорить про HTML... Утрирую, но 80% кода будет обработка ошибок в HTML и 20% - сам анализ :)